# I want to know how I can make it so that the code doesn't stop after the DEPOSIT if condition ends, how can I do that? (PYTHON)

Tags: python

I want to know how I can make it so that the code doesn't stop after the DEPOSIT if condition ends, but intead loops back to the input. How can I do that in Python?

This is my code:

```
print("Welcome to Doge Bank") 
print("How much money would you like to start with?") 
balance = int(input()) 
print("Great! You can type DEPOSIT to DEPOSIT money, BAL to check your BALANCE and WITHDRAW to WITHDRAW money") 
operation = input() 


if operation == "DEPOSIT": 
    print("You have started a deposit operation, say Y to continue") 
    confirm = input() 
    if confirm == "Y": 
        print("How much would you like to deposit?") 
        depositNum = int(input()) 
        balance = balance - depositNum
        print("You have deposited", depositNum, "| Your current balance is", balance)
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here :) we have no idea what you'd like to happen after the DEPOSIT if-condition ends.

Comment: I want it so that they can start from beginning again to continue, but for someone reason the code stops after the DEPOSIT condition is finished

Comment: For example, I did my deposit, then I want to be able to continue from the "Great! You can type DEPOSIT to DEPOSIT money, BAL to check your BALANCE, and WITHDRAW to WITHDRAW money"

Comment: It sounds like you might be interested in reading up about how to make loops in Python that repeat blocks of code: https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/. And how to produce more complex conditional blocks in Python: https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about basic Python constructs (loops) that can be looked up in any text book or tutorial and the purpose of stackoverflow is not to retype tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your are building a prototype for an ATM machine. You could use a while loop like following. ‘while’ literally means keep on looping until the given condition is not violated. Your code ends because ‘if’ statement is not a ‘loop’. If the condition in ‘if’ is fulfilled (i.e if the user selects ‘DEPOSIT’ then the code under it is executed and then it does not ‘loop’)

```
print("Welcome to Doge Bank") 
print("How much money would you like to start with?") 
balance = int(input()) 
session_live = True

while session_live:
    print("Great! You can type DEPOSIT to DEPOSIT money, BAL to check your  BALANCE and WITHDRAW to WITHDRAW money, EXIT to exit.") 
    operation = input() 
    if operation == "DEPOSIT": 
        print("You have started a deposit operation, say Y to continue") 
        confirm = input() 
        if confirm == "Y": 
            print("How much would you like to deposit?") 
            depositNum = int(input()) 
            balance = balance + depositNum
            print("You have deposited", depositNum, "| Your current balance is", balance)
    elif operation == "EXIT":
        print("Thank you for using our ATM")
        session_live = False
```

Here at first the variable `session_live` is set to `True`. It remains `True` unless you change it. The loop continues until you change `session_live` to `False`. In python when you say `“while session_live:”` it means `‘while session_live is True:’` and in fact you can write it as `‘while session_live is True:’`To demonstrate changing the value of `session_live`, I added a condition where if the user selects `“EXIT”` then you change `session_live` to `False`.

Please note that in your code, you reduce the amount that was ‘deposited’ from the balance. Change that to ‘+’ instead of ‘-‘ as I have done here. You can similarly add other ‘elif’ conditions for ‘BALANCE’ and ‘WITHDRAW'

Comment: Wow, whoever gave that ATM PROTOTYPE MACHINE reply thanks, your amazing, I could've never thought of that, ty so much

Comment: You are welcome. Looks like you are just beginning this exciting journey in programming.  Good luck! As Alex suggested above in the comment to your question, read about loops in the link Alex have shared.